# Is Android allowed to start an arbitrary activity of a once killed App?

Tags: android

I have an app that needs to create a session in order to work. When the app is started via it's `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` activity (`LoginActivity`), the session is created nicely, stored in a singleton class and the user is navigated to `MainActivity`.

Now the app tends to crash because the session does not exist. I assume this is because Android started `MainActivity` directly while the previously created session has been killed. Can that be the reason?

Do I need to expect that my app is restarted at any activity?

Comment: you can use shared preferences to store your session related data and recreate your session when app is launched again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely the case, as one example (or used to be as I have not tested this in a while), that the Android 'OS' can start an app at an activity other than main if the app crashed.

This is supported by the Android online documentation which highlights the fact that Android apps can have multiple entry points, unlike many other systems. This can be a bit confusing at first: (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html):

> Therefore, unlike apps on most other systems, Android apps don't have a single entry point (there's no main() function, for example).

This is often used when an activity in one app is available to be 'called' from another application.

I think it is probably going a bit far to say it will be at an arbitrary activity as there is, I think, some logic to it - for example restarting the activity where the crash occurred, or from the point at which it was previously if the app is closed by the system to free up memory etc.

Comment: Thanks. The documentation is focusing on use cases where one app starts another app's activity. As you do, I also guess that the app is restarted at the activity where it was before the process was killed (clean memory priority kill, no crash). But is there any documentation about that?

Comment: I'm not sure about official documentation, but there is an article that is commonly referred to (it is old but I think it explains the design well which help here): http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html. This reddit discussion is also useful, I think, again as it explains the thinking behind the design: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/20y5uf/system_tries_to_restart_each_activity_in_the/

Comment: Thanks, I found it in the given resource: *If a user later returns to an application that's been killed, Android needs a way to re-launch it in the same state as it was last seen, to preserve the "all applications are running all of the time" experience. This is done by keeping track of the parts of the application the user is aware of (the Activities), and re-starting them with information about the last state they were seen in.*